# Set a Child ID to Parent ID in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, relationship

In my application I have a `User` class which has one and only one `Settings` class. A one-to-one relationship 
I have a simple NHibernate mapping for a User:

```
/// NHibernate declarations etc
<id name="squid" type="guid">
  <generator class="assigned" />
</id>
/// Properties
<one-to-one class="Settings" name="Settings" outer-join="true" cascade="save-update" />
/// Close tags & end file
```

And my Settings class is

```
/// NHibernate declarations
<id name="squid" type="guid">
  <generator class="assigned" />
</id>
/// Properties, close tags & end of file
```

So as you can see my User is assigned a guid based from their Active Directory account (or in my unit tests, a new Guid generated by `Guid.NewGuid()`)

Is it possible for NHibernate to magically assign the Settings GUID to be the User GUID?

Comment: Why do you need this? If you mean that Settings instance has no sense without User instance, better define Settings as value object.

Comment: Read here for example: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/09/17/value-objects.aspx

Comment: Hi Pavel, thanks for the link. Do you mind submitting it as the answer so I can vote it as correct? Was what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood your example better define `Settings` as Value object, because it does not make sense without `User`. It's common practice in Nhibernate usage. You can read more about this [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/09/17/value-objects.aspx).